# tuple elements are read-only?

Tags: c++, constants, stdtuple

I'm trying to make a program to scan for HRML tags and their attributes.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>

#include<sstream>
#include<fstream>
#include<list>
#include<numeric>
#include<map>
#include<iterator>

#include<regex>
#include<climits> //#include"matrix.h"
#include<random>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>

#include<set>

using namespace std; 
typedef tuple<string,vector<string>,bool> tagMap;

int main(){
    int n;
    int q;
    cin>>n>>q;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
    set<tagMap> TagHierarchy;
    vector<tuple<string,string,string>> tags;

    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        string ln;
        getline(cin,ln);
        istringstream is{ln};
        string tagId;
        is>>tagId;
        if(find(tagId.begin(),tagId.end(),'/')!=tagId.end()){
            auto it=find_if(TagHierarchy.begin(),TagHierarchy.end(),[&](tagMap e){if(get<0>(e)==tagId)return true;return false;});
            get<2>(*it)=false; // Error is here
        }
        else{
            tagId.erase(remove(tagId.begin(),tagId.end(),'<'),tagId.end());
            for(auto& e:TagHierarchy){
                if(get<2>(e)){//active
                    vector<string> v=get<1>(e);
                    v.push_back(tagId);
                }
                else{//inactive

                }
            }
            TagHierarchy.insert(make_tuple(tagId,vector<string>{},true));
            string tagName;
            is>>tagName;
            char t;
            is>>t;
            string tagValue;
            is>>tagValue;
            tagValue.erase(remove(tagValue.begin(),tagValue.end(),'>'),tagValue.end());
            tags.push_back(make_tuple(tagId,tagName,tagValue));
        }

    }


}
```

The problem lies on line 45, where I scan change the tag to closed, where it gives me the following

```
error: assignment of read-only location 'std::get<2u, {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, bool}>((* & it.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basi|
```

But the tuple isn't const? 
I've also tried for-ranged loops, for each loops, but they all give me the same error.

Comment: *The problem lies on line 45* Probably better to mark the error with a comment in your code ot at least write out the line which you are referring to. There are no line numbers shown in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> tuple elements are read-only?

Not in general. But elements of a const tuple are read-only.

> But the tuple isn't const?

Elements of a set are const. The tuple is an element of the set. Yes, it is const. (Or at least the access is through a const reference; I'm not sure if something is guaranteed about constness of the object itself)

Answer (score 0):

This compiles just fine (used all your includes just in case):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>

#include<sstream>
#include<fstream>
#include<list>
#include<numeric>
#include<map>
#include<iterator>

#include<regex>
#include<climits> //#include"matrix.h"
#include<random>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>

#include<set>

main() {
        std::tuple<std::string,std::string,std::string> t;

        std::get<0>(t) = "123";
        std::get<1>(t) = "234";
        std::get<2>(t) = "345";
}
```